# Clearing form fields, inside a modal

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

```
Rails 5.2
Bootstrap 4
```

I have a modal, with a built-in form. This is a test form, that saves a test note to a table. The save is working fine, but the comment section does not clear when the Save button is clicked.

How can I get it to clear (not close the modal)?

```
#TestModal.modal.fade aria-hidden="true"
  .modal-dialog role="document"
    .modal-content
      .modal-header Test Modal
        h3.modal-title
        button.close aria-label="Close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button"
          span aria-hidden="true"  ×
      .modal-body
        = simple_form_for :test_model, url: test_model_url, method: :post do |f|
          .form_group
            = f.text_area :note, rows: 15
          button.btn.btn-secondary data-dismiss="modal" type="button" Cancel
          button.btn.btn-primary type="submit" Save
```

## Here's what I tried:

```
#TestModal.modal.fade aria-hidden="true"
  .modal-dialog role="document"
    .modal-content
      .modal-header Test Modal
        h3.modal-title
        button.close aria-label="Close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button"
          span aria-hidden="true"  ×
      .modal-body
        = simple_form_for :test_model, url: test_model_url, method: :post do |f|
          #NoteEntryForm.form_group
            = f.text_area :note, rows: 15
          button.btn.btn-secondary data-dismiss="modal" type="button" Cancel
          button.btn.btn-primary type="submit" Save
```

And created a views/notes/create.js.slim, and put in it:

```
javascript:
    $('#NoteEntryForm').val('')
```

But when I try to save, I get the following error message:

```
NotesController#create is missing a template for this request format and variant. request.formats: ["text/html"] request.variant: []
```

Comment: Are you submitting form with ajax?

Comment: I am not. This is a standard .htm.slim view. It is a bootstrap button (the save button), so it is using Ajax courtesy of Bootstrap, not mine

Answer (score 0):

Since the form is being submitted through AJAX/JS you can also respond to it with JS.
You need a view file with the same name as the controller action that receives the submitted params and the view file needs to have .js.slim extension.

Let's say you have a notes controller like this:

```rb
class NotesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @note = Note.new(note_params)
    @note.save
  end
end
```

Then you need a view file called create.js.slim and inside that you can use jquery to clear the form:

```rb
$('#test_model_note').val('');
```

You need to check the DOM if the ID is correct, but I think this will be generator by the form helper in this way.

Comment: If you read the error you can see that it is not submitting the form through AJAX/JS. In order to achieve that you need to add remote: true to the form

Comment: I am not submitting the form through AJAX/JS. It is the .slim file I posted in my question

Comment: If you want to clear the form you need some JS or redirect, but redirecting will also close the modal. By adding remote: true too the simple_form_for it will be submitted through JS and then it will render the create.js.slim file and that file has the JS code to clear your form.

Comment: If you submit the form, can you check the terminal logs and see that it renderd the create.js.slim file?